# Javascript security question / Using eval()

Tags: javascript, security, eval

I'm seeing code in the following form - is such use of eval() safe?

```
function genericTakeAction(frm_name,id,pagenum,action)
{
    var rset=eval("document."+frm_name);

    var x=eval("document."+frm_name+".edit_key");
    var y=eval("document."+frm_name+".cAction")
    if(x)
        x.value=id;
    if(y)
        y.value=action;

    page_list(pagenum);
}
```

Its used as:

```
  <a href="javaScript:;" onClick="genericTakeAction('frmSearch',
  '<?php echo $rec_id;?>','<?php echo $pagenum?>','makeOpen')" 
  class='link6'>Make Open</a>
```

Comment: This is probably #1 on the list of unnecessary uses of `eval`. See Gareth's answer for why.

Answer (score 5):

Whether it's right or wrong, it's needlessly complicated.

```
function genericTakeAction(frm_name,id,pagenum,action)
{
    var rset = document[frm_name];

    var x = rset.edit_key;
    var y = rset.cAction;

    if(x)
        x.value=id;
    if(y)
        y.value=action;

    page_list(pagenum);
}
```

This works because in JavaScript, you can access an object's properties in one of two ways: Either using dotted syntax and a literal identifier, e.g. `x = obj.foo;`, or using bracket syntax and a string identifier, e.g. `x = obj["foo"];`. (Note how `foo` was not in quotes in the first one, but was in quotes for the second; but both do ***exactly*** the same thing. Also note that since the property name is a string in the second case, you can use any expression that results in a string, so `y = "f"; x = obj[y + "oo"];` also works.)

P.S. It's wrong

Comment: However, it's necessary to check if `document[frm_name]` is actually an object / not undefined. Otherwise i'll throw a type error on accessing those propertys.

Comment: @jAndy: True, but then, so would the `eval` version. :-)

Comment: @TJCrowder: sure, but I guess everyone gets my point. Why leaving bugs within an "answer" ?

Comment: I wanted to keep a line-for-line equivalence with the question, to highlight the relevant point (that the `eval` use is unnecessary).

Answer (score 1):

`eval()` is generally frowned upon because, as you are already aware, it is considered unsafe.

In the browser environment, however, it is less of an issue, because in fact, any user could `eval()` any code they wanted to, using tools like Firebug, etc.

There is still an issue, in that the `eval()` embedded in the code can be run without the user knowing that he was triggering an `eval()`, but it's still much less of an issue than in a server-side environment like PHP.

`eval()` is actually typically used as you've shown to run JSON code being returned from a server-side request. Newer browsers can import JSON more safely using a dedicated JSON `parse()` function, but older browsers do not have this function and are forced to use `eval()` for this. Most JSON libraries have `eval()` in their code somewhere for this reason, but will generally do some sanitisation of the input before running it through `eval()`.

Answer (score 1):

Even if it might look a little bit convoluted, as others have already mentioned, from a pure security perspective, you have to make sure that the 'frm_name' parameter of the genericTakeAction() function can never contain user-supplied data.

In your example, the 'frm_name' parameter contains the hard-coded literal 'frmSearch'. So it is ok as long as this genericTakeAction() function does not get called somewhere else with user-supplied data for the 'frm_name' parameter.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting#Traditional_versus_DOM-based_vulnerabilities